# How to edit a Netgear .cfg file on a mac?

Tags: router, backup, text-editors, sublime-text-2

I have a backup from my router Netgear. It created a file backup.cfg. When I  open it in an editor (sublime, vi), it looks like it is encrypted.

When I open it into sublime, it looks like this:

```
½Ïâîýô÷ÃìÇËÏÊÄ”ÌÜ×Ö†¬¨Ç’ôóýååãà…þâåÉ°Üä¶¼´´´¶ÎÑÃÁÛ”ßÎ»§¨
€†<Øª¶=¨³ˆÆÚŽÐÛÅÃÀÈÔÐþ¨º£®‘’ÉŠŸ´†§½¹Ç“„Ô…—ŸÔ‹“²†éŒÉæÿ“žìÄ‰ˆ€û
€.˜çŽìæò©Å¦ô²´ïëµÏÏ“éê–œýå¸°¹ãôî—û–ÕúÑËÐ„Û±ÌøÇœÒƒ‘©ˆù
¢®úÊ”ÈÉ·Ï‡ßõàö…›ÒÔäšù“¦­ó¸³§ùó©¾Ô<‡Ýúœóþ–ŠC ï¡§ÛÛî˜ËÀâ‚ëÌÞœýª¼ŸÁç–†¨Â–
Öð·ñÀÂÒÓÏÜÙÌúäùõëà¯ý—˜îíâõ¼—©¯çåêÑÕŠó‘ú¼¦Óõ¹¯«µ¥°ËÇ¤³Ãè°»×ªÓºœ®/°
```

What can I do to open it in a readable format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### What should I do to open it in readable format?

Unfortunately Netgear have decided, with their newer router models, to use a binary file format for `cfg` files.

These cannot be edited in a text editor (in any meaningful way).

The file format has not been documented by Netgear, so even editing the file with a hex editor won't help.

Answer (score -2):

i tried opening my .cfg file with the tool @
https://www.excentis.com/node/732/download/148498be73f282fee00fdaabed9f5a19

The above tool worked fine for me.

Comment: Can you give more information not just a link?

Comment: the link does't work anymore